# NHibernate Sqldatetime must be between 1/1/1753 and 12/31/9999

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate in my MVC project.
My problem is, while i m trying to update an object i m getting following error.

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and
>   12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

In debug mode I see the date property is not null. I set Datetime nullable on mapping. But I'm still getting sqldatetime error.

```
public class EntityBaseMap<T> : ClassMap<T> where T : EntityBase
{
    public EntityBaseMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.IsDeleted).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.CreatedAt).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.UpdatedAt).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Random).Formula("NEWID()");

        References(x => x.Status).Column("StatusId");

        Where("IsDeleted=0");
    }
}
```

Datetime properties are not null on save.

```
public int SaveOrUpdatePage(PageDto PageDto)
{
    var page = PageDto.Id > 0 ? ById<Page>(PageDto.Id) : new Page();
    var status = PageDto.Status.Id > 0 ? LookupById<Status>(PageDto.Status.Id) : null;
    var type = PageDto.Type.Id > 0 ? LookupById<PageType>(PageDto.Type.Id) : null;
    //var parent = PageDto.Parent.Id > 0 ? ById<Page>(PageDto.Parent.Id) : page.Parent;

    page.Description = PageDto.Description;
    page.Title = PageDto.Title;
    page.SpotText = PageDto.SpotText;
    page.Status = status;
    page.Text = PageDto.Text;
    page.Url = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(PageDto.Url) ? PageDto.Url.ToFileName() : PageDto.Title.ToFileName();
    page.Featured = PageDto.Featured;
    page.Type = type;

    using (var tran = UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.BeginTransaction())
    {
        UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.SaveOrUpdate(page);
        tran.Commit();
    }


    page.CreateDirectory();

    if (PageDto.Id == 0)
    {
        page.Copy();
        page.CopyThumbs();
    }

    SetResultAsSuccess();

    return page.Id;
}
```

I m using SQLServer 2008 and on table datetime columns check with allow null.

Comment: Is the `DateTime` nullable in `Page` and in  `PageDto`?

Answer (score 7):

This is not an issue of `NULL` or *NULLABLE* column. This is an issue of the C# default value of the `DateTime` ValueType.

```
default(DateTime) == new DateTime(1,1,1) // 1st January of year 1
```

So, because the CreatedAt or UpdatedAt is defined as

```
public virtual DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
public virtual DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
```

And never set to other than its default value ... the which value is 1.1.0001. And this is less then SQL Server lower bound 1.1.1753...

Other words, be sure that you set these values to some meaningful values, e.g. **`DateTime.Now`**

Comment: i tried to set DateTime.Now both of two dates before  SaveorUpdate(page). so i m sure that are meaningful values.

Comment: Could be... but then for sure the issue is different column. Simply - almost always - I mean **99,98%** cases, this issue means: there is a `DateTime` property not `DateTime?`. Such property is NOT set with custom value, just left with default 1.1.0001. Check carefuly exception (you will see which column is wrong) and then for sure you will se that its value (in debug) is left on a `default(DateTime)` ... hope it hleps a bit

Comment: yes it is helpful, is there any way to find wrong format record on save ?

Comment: Yes. Tests / Unit tests. I do have my best to keep all (really almost all) entities under basic CRUD tests, to be sure that they are passing mapping-DB. If these test fail, one will get full stack exception with the very descriptive information. NHibernate really has great Exception system. Just observe that full stack and you will see clear answer... Other words, I'd suggest- create your own Tests and start to profit from "sustainable and maintainable" development - driven by tests. I am serious, that's the only way I found ... to be working in any other than short run... does it make senese?

Comment: Great answer Radim. Another option is to set a default date on the database, this way you don't need to remember to set them in c# When I need to remember these types of things I always forget!

Comment: @Rippo correct! good, defaults are there for a reason, good solution ;)